# Why wont it accept my return value?

Tags: java, while-loop, return-value

My code should accept leapyears and run it through the argument to verify if it is a leap year and ignore not leap years by using the argument method at the top but the return value returns an error. so does the printLeap value.

I'm at this over 4 hours and I cannot do it xD. I dont know how to make it ignore the value if it's not a leap year. I'm only new to java and especially new to return values, yes this is homework but the tags don't show the home-work option I tried with and without a dash.

I tried using a double value return ( I, J ) but it returns a result 0 if J is not a leap year. I also tried making it through using a purely if else if else statement but again the same issue... any advice or assistance is greatly appreciated

Here is my ammended code==

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SimpleMath {

```
public static int printLeap(int r, int k){  
    if((r % 4 == 0) && (r % 100 != 0) || (r % 400 == 0)){
    return r;
    }
    else if ((r % 4 != 0) && (r % 100 == 0) || (r % 400 != 0));
    return k;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    while (true) { //while the statement is true (so it continues indefinitely until the break occurs).

        String year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter input year, when done type End");

        if ("End".equals(year)){ //if the user types End then the loop will break. it allows a string to be input for an int value

            break;
        }   {
              int r = Integer.parseInt(year); 

 int k = 0;
int i = printLeap(r, k);
if (i == 0) {
    System.out.println("");
}
else
    System.out.println("This is a leap year:  " + i);   


}
}
}
```

}

Comment: Else should return something as well

Comment: Your function is actually not checking anything - it just returns the input

Comment: There are so many errors in your code.Yes year should get i not the other way around. And initialize yes year to zero first.

Comment: Are you sure this code actually compiles? Variable i in main isn't declared anywhere which makes it accessible in main.

Comment: TBH this code won't even compile and even if it did your entire approach is strange - why are you returning an `int` from your `printLeap` function (which doesn't actually print anything)? What kind of value do you intend to return if the year is not a leap year?

Comment: I see thank you. now it's looking a bit more coherent.

Comment: It should ignore the value if it's not a leap year

Comment: This is a nasty one: `if ((r % 4 != 0) && (r % 100 == 0) || (r % 400 != 0));`. You’ve got a semicolon at the end. This counts as a statement in Java but does nothing. So nothing is done if the condition in the if statement is true.

Comment: Despite the nasty semicolon, your program seems to behave correctly now (with your edit). If I’m allowed to mention it, it could still benefit from a readability polish.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring non-leap years requires an if statement. I suggest:

```
            int r = Integer.parseInt(year);
            if (printLeap(r)) {
                System.out.println("This is a leap year:  " + r);
            }
```

You don’t need the curly braces around these statements.
The above in turn requires that `printLeap` (you can probably think of a better name) returns a `boolean`. That is actually quite simple:

```
private static boolean printLeap(int i) {
    return i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 == 0;
}
```

As an aside, there is an error in your formula for a leap year that I have not corrected. See if you can figure out for yourself.

Comment: thanks very much. as difficult as it is it's quite fun. I'll check it out.